# How to run two task concurrently with Python async/await?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

Code:

```
import asyncio


async def f1():
    print('f1:1')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('f1:2')


async def f2():
    print('f2:1')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('f2:2')


async def f():
    await f1()
    await f2()


asyncio.run(f())
```

Result:

```
f1:1
f1:2
f2:1
f2:2
```

What I expected is run `f1` and `f2` concurrently, and with result:

```
f1:1
f2:1
f1:2
f2:2
```

So could anyone please give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [gather()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently):

```
import asyncio


async def f1():
    print('f1:1')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('f1:2')


async def f2():
    print('f2:1')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('f2:2')


async def f():
    await asyncio.gather(f1(), f2())


asyncio.run(f())
```